# URL Redirect works on localhost but not server

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config, iis-7.5

Here is my `web.config` redirect rule:

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
     <rule name="Redirect from old page">
       <match url="^oldpage.aspx" />
       <action type="Redirect" url="pages/newpage.aspx" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
     </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

On `localhost` this redirect rule works just fine.

When I publish the config file to IIS, the redirect rule seems to break the web application. Every page I try to go to returns a 500 error.

Note: the web application uses an IP addresses instead of domain name.

Example: I want to redirect `http://192.168.168.255:44/oldpage.aspx?queryString=parameter` to `http://192.168.168.255:44/newpage.aspx?queryString=parameter` but I receive a 500 error. Even if I want to visit `http://192.168.168.253`, I receive a 500 error.

IIS says to:

> Delete the malformed XML element from the ApplicationHost.config file or from the Web.config file.

However, I can't identify what is malformed about this redirect rule. It works just fine in the localhost. Should I include the full IP address in the `match url` node? If so, how would I format that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the IIS Rewrite module is also installed on the server? If not IIS will not recognize the Rewrite Node and give a 500 error.
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: stupid of me assuming that it would be installed on all the servers.. thanks!